# Two UICollectionViews and two UICollectionViewCells in one UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have two `UICollectionView`s on my storyboard, each with its own outlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var daysCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var hoursCollectionView: UICollectionView!
```

In each collection view, I want to use a different type of cell. So I created a `DayCell` class and an `HourCell` class.

Then in `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell 
{ 
    if collectionView == self.dayCollectionView 
    {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("dayCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as DayCell
       ...
       return cell
    } 
   else if collectionView == self.hourCollectionView 
   {
       let cell: HourCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("hourCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as HourCell
        ...
    return cell
    }
}
```

I'm getting a compiler error

> Missing return in a function expected to return UITableCellView".

Am I totally missing something or do the returns inside the `if` statements not work in this scenario?

Or am I just going about this totally wrong? This seems to be the answer that everyone is suggesting. I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the `if` condition in your code is not 'exhaustive' i.e. there is situation in which the execution can reach the end of the function and fail to return a cell. (For example, you may introduce an additional collection view in the future)

Here is a simplest fix:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { 
    if collectionView == self.dayCollectionView {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("dayCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as DayCell
        ...
       return cell
    } else { // do not do this check: if collectionView == self.hourCollectionView {
       let cell: HourCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("hourCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as HourCell
        ...
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Not only does this fix my issue, but I feel educated as well. Thanks!